# Jetpack Compose testing with viewmodel state

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to test my composable functions using viewmodel state but it's not working correctly, when i run `counter_ui_increments()` i get 'state 0' instead of 'state 1'. If i use mutableStateOf inside the composable functions instead, everything works fine

```
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
internal class CounterUiKtTest {

    @get: Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel

    @Before
    fun setUp() {

        runBlocking {

            val state = viewModel.counterState.first()

            composeTestRule.setContent {
                CounterUi(
                    count = state,
                    incrementCounter = {
                        viewModel.incrementCounter()
                    },
                    decrementCounter = {
                        viewModel.decrementCounter()
                    }
                )
            }
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun verify_if_all_views_exists() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("counter text").assertExists()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("increment counter icon").assertExists()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("decrement counter icon").assertExists()
    }

    @Test
    fun verify_counter_is_0_to_check_initial_state() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("counter text").assertTextContains("count 0")
    }

    @Test
    fun counter_ui_increments() {
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("increment counter icon").performClick()
        composeTestRule.onNodeWithTag("counter text").assertTextContains("count 1")
    }
}

class MainViewModel: ViewModel() {

    private val _counterState = MutableStateFlow(0)
    val counterState = _counterState.asStateFlow()

    fun incrementCounter() {
        _counterState.value++
    }

    fun decrementCounter() {
        _counterState.value--
    }
}

@Composable
fun CounterUi(
    count: Int,
    incrementCounter: () -> Unit,
    decrementCounter: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(8.dp),
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
    ) {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .testTag("decrement counter icon")
                .size(24.dp)
                .clickable {
                    decrementCounter()
                }
        ) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
                text = "-"
            )
        }

        Text(
            modifier = Modifier
                .testTag("counter text"),
            text = "count $count")

        Box(modifier = Modifier
            .testTag("increment counter icon")
            .size(24.dp)
            .clickable {
                incrementCounter()
            }) {
            Text(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .align(Alignment.Center),
                text = "+"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question contains the answer. You should use/observe states inside your composables

Comment: Doing this would make the composable stateful, something we try to avoid, so instead the state gets passed in as a parameter

Comment: The problem is your composable does not get recomposed. Containing a state does automatically recomposes composable on update. You should avoid using states in composables, so you can make outer composable that calls yours one and passes state as parameter

Comment: did you have time to see my answer? I hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Some workaround to avoid using stateful composables:

Use outer composable. It will be stateful, however inner ones will be stateless and will be recomposed on outer composable's recomposition.

```
@Composable
fun MyScreen() {
    val count by remember { mutableStateOf(counterState) }
    val onCounterChange: (Int) -> Unit = { it -> count = it }

    CounterUI(..., onCounterChange)
}

@Composable
fun CounterUI(..., onCounterChange: (Int) -> Unit) {
    ...
    TextField(
            value = count,
            onValueChange = onCounterChange
    )
    Text("count $count")
}
```

The idea is called state hoisting. Read more in [official doc](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting)